# Не импортирует библиотеку в google colab в коде выложенном на гитхаб

Tags: python, github, pytorch

Запускаю код с [страницы](https://github.com/nianticlabs/wavelet-monodepth/blob/main/NYUv2/sparsity_test_notebook.ipynb)

Пишет ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_wavelets'

я попытался найти pytorch_wavelets. Такого модуля нет, но есть pytorch_wavelet без S.

установил его и попытался получить IDWT с него (Это имя которое используется в коде по первой ссылке). Но опять же проблема, которая звучит как cannot import name 'IDWT'.

В документации на модуль я нашел названия имён DWTForward, DWTInverse. Они тоже не подходят. Интересно и то что описание на библиотеку pytorch_wavelet**S** есть. Но опять же установить не удаётся.

Подскажите, что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить воспользоваться другой библиотекой, такой как `PyWavelets`. Она также имеет модуль `idwt`.

Установка в Google Colab:

```
!pip install PyWavelets
```

Импорт:

```
import pywt
```

Пример кода:

```
x = [3, 7, 1, 1, -2, 5, 4, 6]
cA, cD = pywt.dwt(x, 'db2')
print(pywt.idwt(cA, cD, 'db2'))
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Однако проверить не могу, теперь не грузит эти строки. 
`from networks.decoders import SparseDecoderWave, DecoderWave, Decoder
from networks.encoders import *`
Аналогичная проблема. Но инфы уже по этим модулям найти не смог. Но вс1 равно спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Общим решением для подобных ошибок для кода с github я считаю следующее. Проверить все ли директории сборки воспринимаются компилятором. Я сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, что папка в проекте есть, но компилятор её не видит. Приходится там где нужна конкретная папка указывать путь к ней явно.